# Why is there a horizontal scrollbar in my website on Mobile view?

Tags: html, css, web

So i am making a landingpage but there is a horizontal scrollbar on mobile vieuw if i test it on my mobile and i don't know why. 
I think something is sticking out of it.

[`my codepen link`](http://codepen.io/amirhanif/pen/YZjZRm)

Comment: Your title has horizontal scrollbar and inside your question you have vertical scrollbar...can you clarify?

Comment: it is horzontal sorry, ill update the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scroll-bar removed for me in codepen when I use this code:

```
@import url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.css);
body {
  transition: all 300ms;
  background-color: #1D1F16;
  font-family: 'Product Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  min-height: 100%;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.logo {
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  transform: translate(0px, 90px);
  /*    botder-bottom: 3px solid #D70778;
   botder-top: 3px solid #D70778; */
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .box {
    width: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 0;
    padding: 1em;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .box {
    transform: translate(0px, 90px);
  }
}

.hammerBox {
  width: 60px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.hammer {
  width: 60px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  animation: anim1 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  size: 30px !important;
  text-align: center;
}

@keyframes anim1 {
  0% {
    bottom: 0px;
  }
  25% {
    bottom: 35px;
  }
  50% {
    bottom: 15px;
  }
  75% {
    bottom: 35px;
  }
  100% {
    bottom: 0px;
  }
}

.text1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #D70778;
  margin-bottom: 0px!important;
  text-shadow: -1px 1px 5px #1D1F16;
}
.uc-2 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 5px;
  color: #F5F5F5;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

p > a:hover {
  color: #d9d9d9;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

._14 {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.footer-social-icons {
  width: 350px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.social-icons li {
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    width: calc(100% / 3);
    text-align: center;
}

.social-icons li a {  
  display: block;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  display:block;
}

.fa {
  padding: 10px 14px;
  -o-transition: .5s;
  -ms-transition: .5s;
  -moz-transition: .5s;
  -webkit-transition: .5s;
  transition: .5s;
}

.fa-facebook:hover {
  color: #3d5b99;
}

.fa-snapchat:hover {
  color: #fffc00;
}

.fa-instagram:hover {
  color: #e95950;
}
```

Comment: it is not working, if i open develop mode and then open a mobile device i can stil scroll horizontal and i absolutely dont want that.

Comment: it still let me scroll horizontally

Comment: @amirhanif Is that becuase you have the height of the codepen container bigger than the app, I think if you test it on an actual device it will work, or in the google developer console where you view on specific devices

Comment: i did test it on mobile, it stil has a vertical scroll